# Data frame transformation using transposing and flatening

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
tdelta      A       B     label

 1          11      21      Lab1
 2          24      45      Lab2
 3          44      65      Lab3
 4          77      22      Lab4
 5          12      64      Lab5
 6          39      09      Lab6
 7          85      11      Lab7
 8          01      45      Lab8
```

And I need to transform this dataset into:

```
For selected window: 4

A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4  L1       label
11  24  44  77  21  45  65  22  Lab1      Lab4
12  39  85  01  64  09  11  45  Lab5      Lab8
```

So based on the selected window - 'w', I need to transpose w rows with the first corresponding label as my X values and the corresponding last label as my Y value. here is what I have developed till now:

```
def data_process(data,window):
    n=len(data)
    A = pd.DataFrame(data['A'])
    B = pd.DataFrame(data['B'])
    
    lb = pd.DataFrame(data['lab'])
    df_A = pd.concat([gsr.loc[i] for i in range(0,window)],axis=1).reset_index()
    df_B = pd.concat([st.loc[i] for i in range(0,window)],axis=1).reset_index()
   
    df_lb = pd.concat([lb.loc[0],axis=1).reset_index() 
    X = pd.concat([df_A,df_B,df_lab],axis=1)
    
    Y = pd.DataFrame(data['lab']).shift(-window)
    
    return X, Y
```

I think this works for only the first 'window' rows. I need it to work for my entire dataframe.

Comment: What happens if `w` is 3? Do you expect 3 rows in your output, [rows 0,1,2; rows 3,4,5; rows 6,7]?

Comment: @ALollz that is correct

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a `pivot`, with a lot of cleaning up after the pivot. For the pivot to work we need to use integer and modulus division so that we can group the rows into windows of length `w` and figure out which column they then belong to.

```
# Number of rows to group together
w = 4

df['col'] = np.arange(len(df))%w + 1
df['i'] = np.arange(len(df))//w

# Reshape and flatten the MultiIndex
df = (df.drop(columns='tdelta')
        .pivot(index='i', columns='col')
        .rename_axis(index=None))
df.columns = [f'{x}{y}'for x,y in df.columns]

# Define these columns and remove the intermediate label columns.
df['L1'] = df['label1']
df['label'] = df[f'label{w}']
df = df.drop(columns=[f'label{i}' for i in range(1, w+1)])
```

---

```
print(df)

   A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4    L1 label
0  11  24  44  77  21  45  65  22  Lab1  Lab4
1  12  39  85   1  64   9  11  45  Lab5  Lab8
```

Comment: arent you changing all columns before the #define comment. It will give key error for label1

Comment: I’m just flattening the MultiIndex of tuples into a single level index.

Comment: what is the df['Label1'] on the last third line ? you havent initialised it before

Comment: @KathanVyas the line before that creates that column label when it collapses the MultiIndex.

Comment: But this here is giving me an error of 'KeyError: 'label1''.